# Django : Update ImageField from OneToOne relation

Tags: django, one-to-one

After several hours to try to update a ImageField in the views.py, I need your helps :

**MODEL :**

```
class ImageTeam(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="imageTeam/", null=False)
    team = models.OneToOneField(Team,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="theImage", null=False)
```

**VIEW :**

```
def update_team(request, idTeam):

    try :
        team = Team.objects.get(id = idTeam)    
    except Team.DoesNotExist :
        return redirect(teams)
    ...
   if request.method == "POST" :
       form = updateTeamForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid() and form.has_changed() :
           team.name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
           ...
           imageForm = form.cleaned_data["image"]
           if imageForm :
               if hasattr(team, 'theImage') :
                    team.theImage.image = imageForm
                    print(team.theImage.image) #Good it prints "<ImageFieldFile: imageName.jpg>"
                    team.theImage.save()  #save doesn't works!
                    print(team.theImage.image) #Bad it prints "<ImageFieldFile: None>"      
                else :
                    #works!
                    ImageTeam.objects.create(image = imageForm, team=team)
            ...
```

**TEMPLATE :**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'update_team' team.id %}" class="form-signin">
        {% csrf_token %}
        ...
            <div class="row">
                {{ form.image }}
            </div>
        ...
```

**FORM :**

```
class updateTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'id':'image_team'}))
    ...
    class Meta : 
        model = Team
        exclude = ['image',...]
```

I have tried many solutions (get the instance and save it, use request.FILES['image'], write directly in path...)

So why the imageField is not updated ? 
*I will very happy if I can fix this problem today*

Answer (score 1):

I think problem here is that `imageForm = form.cleaned_data["name"]`. ImageForm is not 'image'. If you want to store file, you need to get the file. 
`form.cleaned_data['image']` is what you need here. Also, I don't see any form field `name` so for sure the save is not going to work.

Also, good technique to debug these kinds of scenarios is do you a debugger like [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb). Just put `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` in the top of your function and step through the code during execution time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes your're right, I make a mistak when I write my question : it's of course ...cleaned_data['image']. I know where the problem is : I will edit my question (see my prints)